# What does it mean to exercise all possible control paths when comparing with pointers?

Tags: c++

This homework question requires me to compare 2 strings using pointers

I was thinking of just comparing the pointer values but I don't know what it's asking for when it's asking for all possible control paths
This is what I have so far.

```
char * ptr1 = nullptr, *ptr2 = nullptr;
char str1[] = "This is a test string";
char str2[] = "This is a test string";
ptr1 = &str1;
ptr2 = &str2;
```

It gives the error "A value type of char (*)[22] cannot be assigned to an entity type of char *. Whats the correct way of initializing it?

Comment: Could you show up what you have tried.

Comment: If you just compare the pointer values, then two different string objects that both contain the same text, will evaluate to not equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign pointers to str1 and str2, you need only write

```
ptr1 = str1;
ptr2 = str2;
```

The right hand side of the statement

```
ptr1 = &str1;
```

results in a pointer to an element of type char[22], which is equal to the length of your string.

Comment: Okay now that I've changed it, how would I compare the strings using the pointers? Doing ptr1 == ptr2 gives a false while doing *ptr1 == *ptr2 gives a true. However *ptr1 and *ptr2 equals to the first element of the string which is 'T' and T == T. How would I do this for the whole string?

Comment: To compare the contents of the two strings, you'll want to use the strncmp type functions. Take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/